# Rails: get data about a model collection, with new model or method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, domain-model

I have a model `Product` with attributes `sales` and `views`. I need to get sales/views count of all the products. Is more correct to implement this as a method and have a call like `Product.all.sales` or create a new model `Stats` and implement as `Stat.products.sales`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RoR so leaving this as a comment, but my immediate instinct is: If Product can implement sales without depending on anything else, then sales should be a method on Product. Otherwise, something else should be responsible for bringing the Product together with the other dependencies needed to implement sales.

Comment: When you say that `Product` has attributes `sales` and `views`, do you mean these are model fields (backed by database storage) or that you've created these as `attr_accessor` for instance variables?  Do these attributes already contain / access the counts that you need?  Is there any additional logic or calculation needed to get the "sales/views count of all products" (e.g. not already available in the `sales` and `views` attributes)?